# Can't Start Nginx: "server" directive is not allowed here

Tags: ruby-on-rails, azure, nginx, passenger

I am trying to get a passenger + nginx instance running. Passenger has been successfully installed however, when going to to http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/ we are receiving a time out error. So, I looked at nginx:

```
garrett@lakemag:~$ sudo nginx -t
nginx: [emerg] "server" directive is not allowed here in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Thus, nginx is not running, which I assume is my problem.

Here is my nginx.conf file:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml applic$

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    #include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
server {
    listen 80;
    server name http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/;

    root /lakemag/public;

    passenger_enabled on;
    passenger_ruby /home/garrett/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/wrappers/ruby;
    }

}
```

Line 65 is where my server {} block starts. I am at a loss to my problem - all of the blocks seem to  be defined appropriately to me. am I missing something?

*EDIT:

```
garrett@lakemag:~$ sudo nginx -t
[sudo] password for garrett:
nginx: [warn] server name "http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/" has suspicious symbols in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:65
nginx: [emerg] unknown directive "passenger_enabled" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:69
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

After Jorge's solution I am now receiving the above errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where says:

```
server name http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/
```

should say:

```
server_name http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/
```

`server` is a directive to define a server block and to identify what server is you should write a `server_name` directive into it

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

To check config file syntax use:

```
nginx -t
```

Comment: remove the "http://" from this line http://lakemagazine.northcentralus.cloudapp.azure.com/ also can you check if you install nginx from passenger install `passenger-install-nginx-module`. Follow this https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/rubygems_rvm/